# Informix trigger to delete records before insert

Tags: informix

I am trying to create a trigger to simply delete records from `systables_growth` table before an insert happens based on the where clause used on the `date_added` column for records older than a certain number of days (in this example, 15 days):

I am using the below:

```
CREATE TRIGGER systables_growth_clnup
INSERT ON systables_growth
DELETE FROM systables_growth
WHERE date_added < (CURRENT - 15 UNITS DAY)
```

I am getting the below syntax error when performing the above.

```
CREATE TRIGGER systables_growth_clnup
INSERT ON systables_growth
DELETE FROM systables_growth
#^
#  201: A syntax error has occurred.
#
WHERE date_added < (CURRENT - 15 UNITS DAY)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow the syntax diagram(s) for [CREATE TRIGGER](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0584.htm), you find that the [*action clause*](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0606.htm) needs either `BEFORE`, `FOR EACH ROW` or `AFTER` as a prefix before the action verbiage, and the [*triggered action*](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0618.htm) segment shows you need parentheses around the triggered action(s).  Hence:

```
CREATE TRIGGER systables_growth_clnup
    INSERT ON systables_growth
    BEFORE (DELETE FROM systables_growth
            WHERE date_added < (CURRENT - 15 UNITS DAY)
           );
```